# Is it possible to calculate y from a x for linear regression in R?

Tags: r

I've got an assignment to do in R, it's about importing data from Excel into R, then using that data to build a linear regression model and plot it. The problem is that the x values are dates (formatted as yyyy-mm-dd), while the y values are ordinary numbers: for an entered date (x), I am supposed to get a y value (to predict it). I just don't know how to write the syntax for it. 
For now, I've come up with this

```
##the data imported from excel
podaci <- readWorksheetFromFile("DnevnaTecajnaLista_01012008-12042017.xlsx", sheet = 1, 
    startRow = 1, endCol = 9) 
##linear regression model
regresija <- lm(Srednji_za_devize ~ Datum_primjene, data = podaci) 
with(podaci, plot(Datum_primjene, Srednji_za_devize)) ##plot
```

[image: sample plot]

```
print(regresija)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Srednji_za_devize ~ Datum_primjene, data = podaci)
# 
# Coefficients:
#    (Intercept)  Datum_primjene  
#     -6.697e+00       9.414e-09
```

This is what I get. I've attached a picture of the plot. Does anyone have a suggestion or a hint which function I should use? I can send the original data as well if anyone wishes to try (if you understand some Croatian).

Comment: Check out `?predict.lm`

Comment: I forgot about using ?, thanks ^^ The only thing that was missing is to convert the date to POSIXct